Error ! ADB and Genymotion : cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
I'm studying frida and Genymotion.
Genymotion install in my docker
but I want to run 'adb' in container.
In Docker, Successful execute .. but In container is occured Error , , like this
"
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037': Address already in use
ADB server didn't ACK

failed to start daemon *
error:
error:
"

My Environment is ..
Ubuntu 16.04
Python 2.7
Frida 11.0.2
adb 1.0.32
Android 8.1
Help me  . .please ...
I want to use adb in my docker container

Genymotion has as far as I remember an own adb version included that can conflict with the one from Android SDK. Thus make sure to set Android SDK path in Genymotion as described in help. If that doesn't help I remember that there is an ENV variable that tells Genymotion the path to adb it should use. Using that it is possible to let it ugnire it's own adb version. BTW don't you think your environment is a little bit outdated?
